# Every non-trivial holomorphic involution on the open unit disc has a unique fixed point

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove the following:

> If $f : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is a non-trivial biholomorphism and $f\circ f = \operatorname{id}$, then $f$ has a unique fixed point.

Uniqueness follows from the Schwarz Lemma, but I haven't been able to establish the existence of a fixed point.

I know that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D}) = \{\lambda T_a \mid \lambda \in S^1, a \in \mathbb{D}\}$ where $T_a$ is the Blaschke factor associated to $a$.

Not all automorphisms have a fixed point (so we need to make use of the fact that $f$ is an involution). For example, $\phi\circ g \circ \phi^{-1}$ where $\phi : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}$ is an isomorphism and $g : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ is given by $g(z) = z + 1$.

Every automorphism extends continuously to the boundary to give a map $\overline{\mathbb{D}} \to \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ (because $\left|\frac{1}{\overline{a}}\right| > 1$), so by Brouwer's fixed point theorem, the extended map has a fixed point, but it may be on the boundary (as in the case of the mapping $\frac{1}{2}(z+1)$).

If $f(\overline{\mathbb{D}}) \subseteq \mathbb{D}$, then $|f(z)| < |-z|$ on $S^1$ so by Rouche's Theorem, $f(z) - z$ and $-z$ have the same number of zeroes in $\mathbb{D}$, namely one, i.e. $f$ has a (unique) fixed point. However, $|\lambda T_a(z)| = |\lambda||T_a(z)| = |T_a(z)| = 1$ if $z \in S^1$, so we can't use this approach.

---

> If anyone knows how to prove that there is a fixed point, I'd appreciate a **hint**.

I apologise in advance if I have overlooked something simple or made a silly error in my attempts above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- Every automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ is a Möbius transformation, hence extends to an automorphism of the Riemann sphere $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$.
- Every Möbius transformation other than the identity has exactly one or two fixed points in $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$.
- Every automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ maps the unit circle to itself.
- Schwarz' reflection principle.

Comment: I haven't quite figured it out yet. There is a Möbius transformation $\psi$ which maps $S^1$ to the real line and the open unit disc to the upper half plane. Then $F = \psi\circ f\circ\psi^{-1}$ is an involution which maps the real axis to the real axis, so by Schwarz' reflection principle, it satisfies $\overline{F(z)} = F(\overline{z})$. It follows that if $f$ has a fixed point in the exterior of the closed unit disc, it has one in the interior of the unit disc. However, I can't see why $F$ couldn't only have fixed points on the real axis (so $f$ only has fixed points on $S^1$).

Comment: Right, the reflection principle says the fixed points are symmetric with respect to the unit circle. Now it remains to see that an automorphism with a fixed point on the unit circle cannot be an involution. For that, we use that $f\lvert_{S^1}$ is an orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $S^1$. An orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $S^1$ with finitely many (but not $0$) fixed points cannot be an involution - why?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to say it, but I think this is the idea. If $z \in S^1$ is a fixed point and $w \in S^1$ is not, then $z, w, f(w)$ is either a triple written with respect to either the clockwise or counterclockwise orientation, but applying $f$ to the triple we get $z, f(w), w$ which is the triple written in the opposite orientation, but this contradicts the fact that $f$ is orientation preserving.

Comment: Right, that's the thing. And I don't know of a more efficient way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Any automorphism for a open unit disk is Möbius transformation of the form:
$\phi(z) = e^{i\theta}\frac{z-a}{\overline{a}z - 1}$for $a\in\mathbb{D}$ and $0\leq\theta<2\pi$.

Using the rule of mapping composition, by property of involution we obtain the involution is a rotation:$\phi(z) = e^{\pi i}z$, hence has a unique fixed point.