# Conformal mapping with 1 fixed point

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Let $H=\{z\in \mathbb C\mid\operatorname{Re}z>0 \text{ and } \operatorname{Im}z>0\}$ be the right-upper plane, and $f:H\longrightarrow H$ a nontrivial conformal map such that $f\circ f=id$. Proof f has exactly 1 fixed point.

Comment: By "right-upper plane", do you mean the first quadrant, or anything above the line $x + y = 0$? Or maybe something else?

Comment: I mean 1st Quadrant

Comment: This is quite a nontrivial problem in my opinion. I would solve this by first composing with conformal maps on both sides so we are working with a function $\hat f \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ and then apply the proof outlined in the post and comments here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836240/every-non-trivial-holomorphic-involution-on-the-open-unit-disc-has-a-unique-fixe

Note all we have to do is make sure we compose in such a way that preserves $\hat f$ being an involution, but if $\phi$ is a conformal map from the first quadrant to the unit disk then...

Comment: ... we can define $\hat f = \phi ^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi$ so that $\hat f \circ \hat f = \phi ^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi \circ \phi ^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi = \text{Id}$ using $f \circ f = \text{Id}$. We essentially then use Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem to guarentee a fixed point on the closed unit disk, use the Schwarz Lemma to conclude the fixed point will be unique, and use a bit of orientability trickery to conclude as outlined in the post I linked